# unable to connect with correct nginx + certbot config

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I have a nginx web app that runs on a Google VM instance and works perfectly but when I try to add SSL support, I can no longer access the site, "Unable to Connect". I believe I correctly configure my nginx config to cater SSL. I can also see in the logs that nginx and certbot are started.

```
http {
    upstream react {
        server client:3000;
    }

    upstream phoenix {
        server web:4000;
    }

    server {
        # Listen to port 443 on both IPv4 and IPv6.
        listen 80 default_server
        listen 443 ssl default_server reuseport;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server reuseport;

        # Domain names this server should respond to.
        server_name tabi.blanknodes.com www.tabi.blanknodes.com;

        # Load the certificate files.
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/tabi/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/tabi/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tabi/chain.pem;

        # Load the Diffie-Hellman parameter.
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/dhparams/dhparam.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         https://react;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass         https://phoenix/api;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /socket {
            proxy_pass https://phoenix/socket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

    }
}
```

Logs:

```
nginx_1     | Starting the Nginx service
nginx_1     | Starting the certbot autorenewal service
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: using the "epoll" event method
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: nginx/1.21.0
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: OS: Linux 5.4.104+
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: start worker processes
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: start worker process 122
nginx_1     | 2021/06/23 13:26:34 [notice] 117#117: start worker process 123
nginx_1     | Couldn't find the dhparam file '/etc/letsencrypt/dhparams/dhparam.pem'; creating it...
nginx_1     | mkdir: created directory '/etc/letsencrypt/dhparams'
nginx_1     |
nginx_1     |     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
nginx_1     |     %                        ATTENTION!                       %
nginx_1     |     %                                                         %
nginx_1     |     % This script will now create a 2048 bit Diffie-Hellman   %
nginx_1     |     % parameter to use during the SSL handshake.              %
nginx_1     |     %                                                         %
nginx_1     |     % >>>>>      This MIGHT take a VERY long time!      <<<<< %
nginx_1     |     %    (Took 65 minutes for 4096 bit on an old 3GHz CPU)    %
nginx_1     |     %                                                         %
nginx_1     |     % However, there is some randomness involved so it might  %
nginx_1     |     % be both faster or slower for you. 2048 is secure enough %
nginx_1     |     % for today and quite fast to generate. These files will  %
nginx_1     |     % only have to be created once so please be patient.      %
nginx_1     |     % A message will be displayed when this process finishes. %
nginx_1     |     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
nginx_1     |
nginx_1     | Will now output to the following file: '/etc/letsencrypt/dhparams/dhparam.pem'
nginx_1     | Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
nginx_1     | This is going to take a long time
```

I'm using [docker-nginx-certbot](https://github.com/JonasAlfredsson/docker-nginx-certbot) for my nginx + certbot.

Comment: have you tried without `ssl_dhparam` , I don't normally use it. Also "This MIGHT take a VERY long time" can mean it may not have finished (so `nginx` isn't yet running). 2048 bits of entropy can take a long time to collect if you're using `random` not `urandom`, unless you have an entropy generator running, like `haveged`, but this depends on the system, CPU & drivers

Comment: https://scaron.info/blog/improve-your-nginx-ssl-configuration.html <- this guy suggests you use `openssl` to generate the DH params in advance

Comment: Aside from ssl_dhparan, is there any wrong in my config?

Comment: looks fine to me, but I've not actually tried it - you can use `nginx -t` or `nginx -T` to test your config file syntax. Also there's nothing wrong with the `ssl_dhparam` as such, its just that it can take *ages*, so will probably delay the server being able to answer queries. Check the error log.